# On Google Forms, can i set a default on a radio button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to figure out if I can make one of the radio button choices a default, but is not possible on Google Forms? https://www.google.com/forms/about/

Is is not possible even with the Google app script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the option to pre-fill a form and set up the defaults you wish - leaving other fields blank. Then share the link to that pre-filled form rather than the original.

You can do this either using the menu options from the form editor, or by constructing a formResponse in google apps script.

[image: Google Forms menu for 'Get pre-filled link']

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I suppose that this is the only option, doesn't it? Thank you so much for this!

Comment: To create a default using a pre-filled form is the only option with Google forms at the moment. You could always file a suggestion to add this feature in future.

Comment: You can make the pre-filled forms using Apps Script too, this can be useful if you want to set different values for different groups of users, or even individual users, based on data you already have elsewhere. I use this on forms where I have the info already (like an address) but it may have changed. So I'll send it out pre-filled with the user's address so they can edit if needed.

Comment: You do end up with pretty long URLs, so it's worth using google's shortening service which makes them look a lot tidier. Get a long URL once you've created a formResponse with your defaults by using formResponse.toPrefilledUrl(); Then use the shortener: form.shortenFormUrl(formUrl);