# Is there any way to set default choice on a Google forms?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I recently have been really into Google Appscript. I have a form that people will use to order some things. We track their emails. Most of the time people pick one particular option. I want to set that as the default option. If I can do that, I will try to get their email as soon as they load the with `form.getResponses.getRespondentEmail` to parse for a name in my Google sheets. My question is, How Do I set a default value from google Appscript? I went through their documentation but didn't find anything. Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Google Forms, can i set a default on a radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653020/on-google-forms-can-i-set-a-default-on-a-radio-button)

Comment: I know this one. It will solve one of my problems. The one where I want to set a name based on the email however is not benefited by this. Anyway. thanks

Comment: For the email you can only use `getRespondentEmail()` it after they have submitted the Form, and only if you set it up to store the email. I think what you want to do would be better suited to a sort of newsletter; construct the pre-filled form from the list of your emails and then send it to the users. You cannot edit or read data from a Form until it is submitted.

Comment: ** cant Edit before they submit?** that's a bummer. I can't send it per user basis, as it is mostly a public form.

Comment: Afraid not, You can only manage the information after it has been submitted, there is no way to access the Form while the user is responding. You can use [Form sections](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) to manage questions based on previous answers, but that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

You can set default values only if you create a pre-fill link.

[Send a form with pre-filled answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en)